# In a nested list, how to move a tree node (by matching it by name) one level up?

Tags: r, list

### Introduction

Let's say I have a list of lists of lists.... Now I know there are elements in this tree that happen to be lists of one element only. Let's say too I know the name of those elements.

### Problem

Question: How to traverse the tree and un-nest (peel off one layer) those elements?

I am looking for a function that takes two arguments: 
1. the input list
2. name of the elements to peel off.

### Example

In the example below I have that list/tree `input_list`. Now, I want to move the contents of all elements under element `'x'` one level up.

So I want lists `x = [9:0x560f96c34f38]` and `x = [14:0x560f96c34de8]` to be discarded but have their contents moved one level up, in these case, list `y` and `t` should become direct child nodes of `g` and `h`.

The `desired_list` illustrates the desired result.

Note: I used the package `lobstr` to show the tree structure but I guess there might be more visually appealing alternatives... Feel free to suggest.

```r
library(lobstr)

input_list <- list(a = list(b = 1:2, c = 'tricky', d = list(e = 'business', f = 'what?'), g = list(x = list(y = 'aassd')), w = list(z = 'foo')), h = list(x = list(t = 'asd'), s = list(a = 'bar')))

desired_list <- list(a = list(b = 1:2, c = 'tricky', d = list(e = 'business', f = 'what?'), g = list(y = 'aassd'), w = list(z = 'foo')), h = list(t = 'asd', s = list(a = 'bar')))

lobstr::ref(input_list)
#> █ [1:0x560f96c24af8] <list> 
#> ├─a = █ [2:0x560f96c0bb88] <list> 
#> │     ├─b = [3:0x560f960f4ea0] <int> 
#> │     ├─c = [4:0x560f95851ad0] <chr> 
#> │     ├─d = █ [5:0x560f96c24bf8] <list> 
#> │     │     ├─e = [6:0x560f95851a60] <chr> 
#> │     │     └─f = [7:0x560f95851a28] <chr> 
#> │     ├─g = █ [8:0x560f96c34ec8] <list> 
#> │     │     └─x = █ [9:0x560f96c34f38] <list> 
#> │     │           └─y = [10:0x560f95851980] <chr> 
#> │     └─w = █ [11:0x560f96c34e58] <list> 
#> │           └─z = [12:0x560f958518d8] <chr> 
#> └─h = █ [13:0x560f96c24b78] <list> 
#>       ├─x = █ [14:0x560f96c34de8] <list> 
#>       │     └─t = [15:0x560f95851830] <chr> 
#>       └─s = █ [16:0x560f96c34d78] <list> 
#>             └─a = [17:0x560f95878840] <chr>
lobstr::ref(desired_list)
#> █ [1:0x560f95079a28] <list> 
#> ├─a = █ [2:0x560f9465d288] <list> 
#> │     ├─b = [3:0x560f948ae058] <int> 
#> │     ├─c = [4:0x560f958798b8] <chr> 
#> │     ├─d = █ [5:0x560f95078928] <list> 
#> │     │     ├─e = [6:0x560f95879880] <chr> 
#> │     │     └─f = [7:0x560f95879848] <chr> 
#> │     ├─g = █ [8:0x560f94493d58] <list> 
#> │     │     └─y = [9:0x560f95879810] <chr> 
#> │     └─w = █ [10:0x560f94493dc8] <list> 
#> │           └─z = [11:0x560f958797d8] <chr> 
#> └─h = █ [12:0x560f95078de8] <list> 
#>       ├─t = [13:0x560f958797a0] <chr> 
#>       └─s = █ [14:0x560f94493ea8] <list> 
#>             └─a = [15:0x560f95879768] <chr>
```

Comment: This smells a bit of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... where did you get this list from? is it `XML`? If so, perhaps some XML methods are appropriate. Otherwise maybe a use case for `rapply`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico: my lists are objects obtained from parsing JSON responses. Then there is some level of simplification I want to perform on those objects, which includes peeling off at some nodes.